# Optimize query performance

Tags: php, mysql, database

My Appliation(using php) performance is very slow due to more data in my mysql table, My table Structure as follows,

```
`CREATE TABLE `xxxxx` 
(`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `IP` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `Cname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `Port` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT'3306',
 `Variable` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `moddate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Servertime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`moddate`),
 KEY `idx_variable` (`Variable`) ) 
  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85054928 DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2
    /*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST ( MONTH (moddate))
    (PARTITION Jan VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Feb VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Mar VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Apr VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION May VALUES IN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Jun VALUES IN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Jul VALUES IN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Aug VALUES IN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Sep VALUES IN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Oct VALUES IN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION Nov VALUES IN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION DECM VALUES IN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB) */`
```

And It has around 4.2 GB data. My select statement for fetch data is,

```
SELECT 
      `status`,
      `moddate` 
   FROM 
      `xxxxxx` 
   WHERE 
          Cname='xxxx' 
      and ip='0.0.0.0' 
      and port='3306' 
      and Variable='xxxxxx' 
      and status REGEXP '^[0-9]+$|^ON$' 
      and moddate between '2015-01-01 00:47' and '2015-02-01 01:07';
```

but it takes 4:00 min. Since 15 days i have been suffering by this problem. I know we need to put index on column. But I don't know how to optimize this. Could you please any one suggest me which field needs to indexed. or share any other link to optimize my application. thanx...

Comment: 4.2 GB of data really isn't that much for a database, I don't think this should be taking 4 minutes unless you're running your DB on a TI calculator or something... Try to get rid of the REGEX query and index the `Cname` and `port` columns, see if that helps.

Comment: What are the other queries that you run on this database? You could create a composite index on the following: Cname, IP, port, moddate. status may not be included as I am assuming it will not have too many different values. If it does, include that too.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to the where clause and try to determine what might be the smaller result set field first and have that in the first position of a composite index

You may have many entries for the client "xxxxx", but a smaller set on the IP address.  Not sure what your "Variable" context is, maybe this is smaller.  But I would try on

```
( IP, port, cname, variable, moddate, status )
```

but that is basically an index on ALMOST everything.  So, that said, I might chop it down to see performance based on...

```
( IP, port, cname, moddate )
```

After thinking more on it, having CName in first position is probably better...

```
( CName, IP, port, variable, moddate, status )
```

as it hit me cname is probably like a website address, and since a server on a single IP can host many website names, the CName would be smaller than the overall IP address.

Comment: if i want add index,which columns should add index?

Comment: @user3113732, its not that you add  an index for each individual column, you create ONE INDEX that is inclusive of  the many columns as depicted above... such as (CName, IP, Port, variable, ModDate, status ) ... all as a SINGLE index

Comment: @user3113732, not really, it would still have to update an index, but if 1 field vs 5 fields as the key, its still updating.  It would be MINIMAL.

Comment: so you mean to say that it will not be affecting DML operation.

Comment: @user3113732, correct, the data manipulation still does what it does... the engine handles the indexes, partitions, etc for you already your PK and Variable indexes, this just happens to be one more for it to write when any insert/updates happen.   The time it does it would be in milliseconds anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT status, moddate
FROM xxxxx 
WHERE Cname = 'xxxxxx' and
      ip = '0.0.0.0' and 
      port = 3306 and
      Variable = 'TABLE_LOCKS_IMMEDIATE' and
      status REGEXP '^[0-9]+$|^ON$' and
      moddate between '2015-01-01 00:47' and '2015-02-01 01:07';
```

Note:  `port` is an integer so I removed the single quotes around `3306`.  Sometimes, in some databases, the use of mixed comparisons can affect the use of indexes (although probably not in this case).

Your query is accessing one table, so the place to start with defining an index is the `WHERE` clause.  An index that has all six columns mentioned in the table is called a "covering" index.  And a covering index is usually the best for performance.

For such an index, start with the columns that have equality conditions.  Then you get one position for inequalities and `in`.  Then the rest of the columns are in the index just so the engine doesn't have to access the data pages.  So, the best index is `xxxxxx(Cname, ip, port, Variable, moddate, status)`.  The ordering of the first four columns does not make a different for this query, because all have equality indexes in the `from` clause.

Comment: In covering index we can cover all the values in one index. Now my problem is data are keep on inserting into this table. So if i add all the column in index will it affect DML performance?

Comment: @user3113732 . . . Adding *any* index will affect DML performance.  The fact that it is a covering index shouldn't really be any more overhead.